# How to create a non-administrator user in openshift 3.11?

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

In OCP 3.11 (OKD), how can we create a non admin user? Are there any specific commands for it?

Answer (score 2):

As you know, OpenShift provides just built-in admin user "system:admin" by default after just installed.
If you need to use the additional user accounts, you first configure "identity providers" for that.
Because OpenShift does not have authentication feature, it depends on external authentication system completely. Such as LDAP, HTPasswd and so on.
Refer [Configuring identity providers](https://docs.okd.io/3.11/install_config/configuring_authentication.html#identity-providers-configuring) for more details.

There are the configuration details as follows.

1. Configure the "Identity Providers" appropriately to your OKD cluster.
2. Then you can login other users through the Identity Provider you configured.
3. The user you login has the non-administrator permissions by default.

I hope it help you.